# WARNING diagnostic: warning: The following options were not > recognized by any processor: '[openjpa.source, openjpa.metamodel]'

Tags: java, openjpa, openjpa-maven-plugin

Getting this warning on the Open JPA annotation processor/maven plugin?  What is the issue?  On another project I don't get this warning.

> [WARNING] diagnostic: warning: The following options were not
>   recognized by any processor: '[openjpa.source, openjpa.metamodel]'

```
      <plugin>
            <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>process</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <processors>
                            <processor>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.meta.AnnotationProcessor6</processor>
                        </processors>
                        <optionMap>
                            <openjpa.metamodel>true</openjpa.metamodel>
                            <openjpa.source>7</openjpa.source>
                        </optionMap>
                        <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/metamodel</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <!-- OpenJPA -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId>
                    <artifactId>openjpa</artifactId>
                    <version>${org.apache.openjpa.version}</version>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId>
                    <artifactId>openjpa-all</artifactId>
                    <version>${org.apache.openjpa.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this warning when there were no entities to process - I simply forgot to add the @Entity Annotation to my entity class.